# Cant get value from struct wrapped in NSValue

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, struct, singleton

I need to pass a struct `AudioStreamBasicDescription` to a random view controller. In order to that I have created a singleton class and I want to store `AudioStreamBasicDescription` in that singleton class.

When the other view controller needs to use the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` I want to get the values inside of that struct.

set:

```
sharedCache.asbdValue=[NSValue valueWithBytes:&asbd objCType:@encode(AudioStreamBasicDescription)];
```

get:

```
sharedCache=[JITCaches sharedManager];
//AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd from singleton
NSValue *value =sharedCache.asbdValue;
AudioStreamBasicDescription desc;
asbd=[value getValue:desc];
```

The error I am getting is

**'AudioStreamBasicDescription' (aka 'struct AudioStreamBasicDescription') to parameter of incompatible type void**

I declare asbd and singletons asbd as

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;   // description of the audio
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (as I'm sure you know) is these lines:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription desc;
asbd=[value getValue:desc];
```

That is not how you call `getValue:`. There are two things wrong:

1. You need to supply (where you are saying `desc`) the *address* of a buffer, not (as you are doing) the *name* of an uninitialized variable.
2. You do not assign the result to anything (`asbd=`). There is no result. The value goes into the buffer (which you are trying to set up as `desc`).

So, I think what you want to say (don't hold me to this) is:

```
[value getValue:&desc];
```

Comment: And see the documentation, which seems to cover this pretty nicely: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Values.html